# How to make an card view that has an image view have rounded corners

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

I have spent the last week just trying to figure out how I can make this `transition_preview` image view have a rounded corner that grows with the card view. I tried using the roundedCorner solution provided to us by `Glide` but I can not seem to solve that problem, when it expands it has this weird space see image that is left.

Here is my code on that part: how can I make it well rounded? I tried this solution but did not give me any issue. I can't of want this type of behaving but expanding up [StackOverflow Question][2]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipChildren="false">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back_btn"
                android:contentDescription="@string/back_button"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/video_preview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,4:5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_max="@dimen/preview_max_width"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="69dp">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/video_container"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#000000" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/transition_preview"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
                </FrameLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Material Card View for corner radius

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/userCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avtar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="Hello"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Add you Image as per your requirement.